# How to create table postgresql when start by docker compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I know this question is already asked and also answer given. But it is not working for me. I follow the same. My postgres container is running fine. I checked inside the container that /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql exist.I used the following docker-compose.yml.

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: postgres
    expose:
    - 5432
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    environment:
         - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
         - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
         - POSTGRES_DB=dev
    restart: unless-stopped

# APP
  profile_editor2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    network_mode: bridge
    container_name: profile_editor2
    volumes:
      - ./image:/app/image
    expose:
      - 8080
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    links:
      - postgres
volumes:
  postgres-data:
```

init.sql:-

```
  create table sometable(id int);
```

No table created. I can see only the database is created. How do I create a table and also if possible insert some data into the table?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write your queries inside init.sql, in this squence:-

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS test_db;    

CREATE DATABASE test_db;    

\c test_db;        

CREATE TABLE Role(
RoleID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
RoleName varchar(50),
);    
insert into Role(RoleName)
values ('Admin'),('User');
```

Comment: I will create a database and role. Not the table. I can create a database and default user postgres is fine for me. I couldn't create table.

Comment: it will create a table Role inside database test_db.

Comment: Those r created by    environment:
         - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
         - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
         - POSTGRES_DB=dev I need to create a table .

Comment: are you checking  "sometable" inside "\c dev"  database ? Your init.sql is fine.

Comment: yes. "\c dev" and there is no table created. Looks like postgres didn't pick up that init.sql.